# Error while using INNER JOIN in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

As I am new to PostgreSQL so I'm using [PostgreSQL sample database](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/) for learning and practicing PostgreSQL. My problem statement is to find payment done for top 15 highest spending customers who rented movies during the days of April 10-13? My query is as follows:

```
SELECT customer.first_name,payment.amount
FROM customer
  INNER JOIN payment ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id 
                      FROM (
                        SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount)
                        FROM payment
                        WHERE extract(month from payment_date) = 4
                        AND extract(day from payment_date) BETWEEN 10 AND 13
                        GROUP BY customer_id
                        HAVING SUM(amount) > 5
                        ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
                        LIMIT 15
                      ) AS top_fifteen);
```

I'm getting following error:

```
relation "customer" does not exist
```

I'm not sure why am i getting this exception here, Can someone help me here in mitigating this issue? Any lead is highly appreciated.

Comment: Relation "Customer" does not exist means that the table or view called customer is not present from where the SQL is run. -   Check you are using the correct database,  that the Customer table is in the same schema ( you may need dbo.Customer) or you are running the query in the correct server - (also case sensitive ) eg Customer vs customer can be considered different

Comment: are you running this query in context of the dvdrental db?

Comment: I'm using correct database and server as i'm able to run other queries correctly. Yes i am running this in context of dvdrental db.

Comment: Are you running this in GUI tool(i.e. PgAdmin X) or from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use table alias name as like below and try

```
SELECT c.first_name,p.amount
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN payment p
ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id IN 
(
SELECT customer_id FROM 
    (
SELECT  customer_id, SUM(amount)
FROM payment
WHERE extract(month from payment_date) = 4
AND extract(day from payment_date) BETWEEN 10 AND 13
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING SUM(amount) > 5
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
LIMIT 15) AS top_fifteen);
```

i rewrite your query as like below

```
select * from
 (
 select  c.first_name,c.last_name,
 sum(amount) as pay_amount,
 count(p.customer_id) pay_num from payment p
 inner join Customer c on  p.customer_id=c.customer_id
     where extract(month from p.payment_date) = 4
AND extract(day from p.payment_date) BETWEEN 10 AND 13
 group by c.first_name,c.last_name,p.customer_id
 ) T 
 order by pay_amount desc
 Limit 15
```

Comment: @KeshavTaparia could you pleases check just executing select * from customer what return this query

Comment: @KeshavTaparia i have changed your query could you check please

Comment: Looks like it was an intermediate issue. Issue got resolved now. Thanks for looking into it.